# Retrieving and deleting e-mails thru POP3 or IMAP using PHP

Tags: php, imap, pop3

is there any way to retrieve the e-mails (sender, subject, body etc.) from 3rd party server (e.g. hotmailo) and then delete them?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/imap

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html